# Using Mongoose in Total.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, total.js

I tried a sample example of **total.js** for REST APIs and I noticed that its all using the NoSQL module. I need to convert this sample to work with MongoDB instead. Is it Possible to use mongoose for mongoDB to work in total.js

Answer (score 0):

Yes and absolutely **you can use Mongoose with Total.js**. Only you need to rewrite processing of data in schemas, it's not hard. Try to look into the Mongoose documentation and start there.